# cannot access a disposed object Datacontext asp.net 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await, asp.net-core

In asp.net 5/core I want to delete an item from my db with a delay using async.
I'm using DI to inject my Datacontext (db) in the class.

I created the following method:

```
public async void DeleteItemAfterTimeAsync(int itemId, TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    // give user time to fill out data
    await Task.Delay(timeSpan);
    var item = db.Items.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == itemId);
    if (item!= null && item.Status == someStatus)
    {
        db.Items.Remove(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

After the given time the method is executed as planned but I get an exception: 'cannot access a disposed object' which is probably because the service is disposed because of the delay.
Should i resolve a new instance of my datacontext in the method or how should I fix this?
Any ideas?
Thanks for helping out in advance.

UPDATE:

Calling the method:

```
await DeleteItemAfterTimeAsync(item.Id, new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
```

Updated method:

```
public async Task DeleteItemAfterTimeAsync(int itemId, TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
   // give user time to fill out data
   await Task.Delay(timeSpan);
   var item = db.Items.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == itemId);
   if (item != null && item.Status == someStatus)
   {
      db.Items.Remove(item);
      db.SaveChanges();
   }    
}
```

Exception occurs on db.Items.Remove(item);

Comment: How is the Datacontext registered? As Transient?

Comment: Have you tried using `async Task` instead of `async void`?

Comment: In startup.cs:   services.AddEntityFramework()             .AddSqlServer().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

Comment: The instance of DbContext is probably created per request so as soon as the request ends it is disposed of. Due to ur delay u try to operate on a disposed object (because the request already completed)

Comment: @Domysee this helps indeed. Strange thing: I can do the FirstOrDefault call without problems, but when I call db.Items.Remove(item) I see 'Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in EntityFramework.Core.dll' in my output window and execution stops...

Answer (score 5):

Because your `DeleteItemAfterTimeAsync` method is an `async void`, it can't be awaited and, by the time you use the db context, it has already been disposed.

Change the `DeleteItemAfterTimeAsync` method to `async Task` and `await` it.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, but I already tried that. Still get a 'Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in EntityFramework.Core.dll' when I try to call Remove(item). Querying the Id is no problem...

Comment: And the code calling `DeleteItemAfterTimeAsync`? Is it `async void`? Somethng is calling `Dispose` on `db` before `DeleteItemAfterTimeAsync` runs to the end.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The reason was that I had a async method deeper in the call stack which was not called with 'await'. (in your example the method using 'await DeleteItemAfterTimeAsync' would not be called with await itself)

The DbContext used was dependency injected in the object calling without await. I guess the DbContext was disposed when I didn't await the async method.

By now you surely have solved your problem, but it might be a good idea to check the call stack!